# Pushing to git repository hosted by Visual studio online without entering user name and password

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a git repository hosted by Visual Studio online. And I want write a script that will automatically Add, Commit and push.

I wrote this:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "commit_$date"
git push -u origin
```

But when it runs, it always asks me to enter my credentials.
how can I integrate the credentials into the push command?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using HTTP for Git, you want to [set up a Git credential helper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github).

Comment: @birryree You should make this an answer!